# Laravel 5 ElFinder Class replace-this-with-your-middleware does not exist error while browse server

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5, elfinder

I have configured elfinder in Laravel 5 and also using CKEditor. Everything was fine till until I click on browse server button and then I got `"Class replace-this-with-your-middleware does not exist`" error.

I have searched the web but I did not find any suitable answer. What can I try next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write your middleware name in elfinder configs.

for example:

```
  'route' => [
    'prefix' => 'elfinder',
    'middleware' => 'auth'/*replace-this-with-your-middleware*/, //Set to                       null to disable middleware filter
],
```

[image](http://clip2net.com/s/3mod0kO)

Comment: Which is located at `/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/config/elfinder.php`. Don't forget to add the `files` folder in your `public` folder .

Comment: Thanks buddy that working. Now i am testing it will work with and data should save into database.

Comment: I was under the impression you should never change files in the vendor directory, as they would be overwritten when you run composer install or update. Is this not correct?

Comment: Hi, Carey Estes,
Yes, You're right, You should never change files in vendor, unless you're not sure Your project won't be updated